# Need help to find a basis of polynomial subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbb{P}$ be the linear space of all polynomials, $\mathbb{P}_4 = \{p \in \mathbb{P} | \text{deg}\ p\leq 4\}$, and $Q=\{p \in \mathbb{P}_4| p(x) = x^4p(\frac1x)\}$. Show that $Q$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{P}_4$. Find a basis of $Q$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. SS nicely formatted your question using MathJax which greatly helps readability. It would greatly help if you could tell us what you've tried and where you are confused as it shows you have attempted the problem. Regards

Answer (score 6):

Some hints rather than a full solution, since this is tagged as homework:

- Suppose that we have some fixed $p(x) = ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$.  Can you write down the polynomial $q(x) = x^4p(\frac1x)$?
- What does it mean (in terms of the coefficients $a, b, c, d,$ and $e$) for $p(x)$ to identically equal $q(x)$?
- What does that imply a typical element of $Q$ 'looks like'?
- And finally, can you extrapolate from that to find a basis?

Comment: q(x) = a + bx + cx^2 + dx^3 + ex^4. Right?

Comment: @Chegevarik Exactly so!  So if the polynomials are to be identically equal, the coefficients corresponding to matching powers have to match...

Comment: So basis will be (x^4+1, x^3+x, x^2) ?

Comment: @Chegevarik That looks correct to me! Nicely done.  (Though you should also, which I forgot to note, show that they form a linear space - that the sum of any two polynomials in $Q$ is also in $Q$, and that any polynomial in $Q$ multiplied by a constant yields a polynomial in $Q$.  But that should be easy.)